# Elasticsearch - MapperParsingException[Malformed content, must start with an object]

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I am trying to bulk index document into ES using BulkDescriptor in C#.  i am using V1.7 ES. Following is my piece of code,

```
 public IBulkResponse IndexBulk(string index, string type, List<string> documents)
        {

                BulkDescriptor descriptor = new BulkDescriptor();
                foreach (var doc in documents)
                {
                    JObject data = JObject.Parse(documents); 

                    descriptor.Index<object>(i => i
                        .Index(index)
                        .Type(type)
                        .Id(data["Id"].toString())
                        .Document(doc));
                }
                return  _Client.Bulk(descriptor);

        }
```

But it is not inserting the documents, When i verified the response i saw the following message `MapperParsingException[Malformed content, must start with an object]`

Sample JSON document

```
{
"a" : "abc",
"b": { "c": ["1","2"]}
}
```

What went wrong in it?

Comment: What version of NEST do you use?

Comment: HI @Rob, It is     v 1.7.1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Issue here is passing raw json through strongly typed fluent bulk method.

What you are actually sending to elasticsearch is

```
{"index":{"_index":"test1","_type":"string"}}
"{"a" : "abc","b": { "c": ["1","2"]}}"
```

which is not correct.

Few ideas what you can do about this:

1. use `JObject` to send correctly serialized object to elasticsearch

   ```
   descriptor.Index<JObject>(i => i
       .Index(index)
       .Type(type)
       .Id(data["Id"].toString())
       .Document(JObject.Parse(doc)));
   ```
2. take advantage of using `.Raw` client to send raw json

   ```
   var json = new StringBuilder();
   json.AppendLine(@"{""index"":{""_index"":""indexName"",""_type"":""typeName""}}");
   json.AppendLine(@"{""a"" : ""abc"",""b"": { ""c"": [""1"",""2""]}}");

   _Client.Raw.Bulk(json2.ToString());
   ```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, It worked for me. Initially i have used Raw, But however i am not sure how to set the _id value. Is there any way to set _id in RAW.

Comment: This should work `"{""index"":{""_index"":""indexName"",""_type"":""typeName"", ""_id" : ""1"" }}"`.